# Why does Wien's law not work for lower frequencies?

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength, approximations

I just found out [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_approximation) is only a good approximation at high frequencies/small wavelengths but am not sure why. Does anyone mind explaining?

Answer (score 4):

Wien's law is indeed an approximation at high frequency that you can obtain from Planck's law. The difference between the two is that Wien's law doesn't take into account the quantum nature of the photons and uses the Boltzmann distribution instead of Bose-Einstein for computing their energy density.

Answer (score 4):

First it's not talking  about
$$\lambda_\text{peak}T=\text{a constant}$$

The exact expression for the spectral energy density of the  black body given by
$$u_\nu=\frac{8\pi h}{c^3}\frac{\nu^3}{e^{\beta h\nu}-1}$$
The crucial
insight is that electromagnetic waves in a cavity can be described by
simple harmonic oscillators.

For large frequencies $e^{\beta h\nu}-1\rightarrow e^{\beta h\nu}$
$$u_\nu=\frac{8\pi h}{c^3}\nu^3e^{-\beta h\nu}$$

which is what derived by Wien approximation.

---